# UINavigationController Storyboard Hopping

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I would like to know what code is required to traverse the storyboard from a `UIViewController` located at index N of a `UINavigationController` which is embedded in a `UITabBarController`, to a similarly embedded `UIViewController`.

I would also like all `UIViewController`s to be popped in the source `UINavigationController`

Direct segues (as shown in red) do not fit my use case.

Swift please.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can pop to the root view controller then change the selected index of the index of the tab bar controller then push whatever view controllers you need on the other navigation controller. For example:

```
    let tabBarController = self.tabBarController;
    let indexZeroNavController:UINavigationController = self.tabBarController?.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController

    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

    tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0

    let newViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("New View Controller")
    let otherNewViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Other New View Controller")

    indexZeroNavController.pushViewController(newViewController!, animated: true)
    indexZeroNavController.pushViewController(otherNewViewController!, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyowulf's approach used to be valid, but things have changed.  In the viewController you wish to pop to, define an "unwind segue".  [example](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/) Once it's defined, you can drag from a button to "exit" and select that unwind segue.

The way unwind segues work has been completely reworked in xcode 7, so you don't have to worry too much about the view controller stack.